# Should Person of Interest be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I personally think [Person of Interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Person_of_Interest_%28TV_series%29) is *just barely* in the Sci-Fi realm, for being centered around a fictional, near-omniscient automated surveillance network. It also has some themes that overlap with other common Sci-Fi/Fantasy stories, such as vigilante heroes and government conspiracies. Overall though, it seems a bit closer to crime drama (as mentioned on Wiki) than true Sci-Fi.

I'm asking because I have a question about the show which is actually not about any of the Sci-Fi aspects. I can see that there is already [one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8076/why-are-all-of-the-persons-of-interest-in-new-york-city) about the show here - with an accepted answer from myself, no less. However, I thought it might be best to double-check here before making a habit of asking about the series on Sci-Fi instead of Movies & TV.

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but from the Wikipedia entry I'd agree with your "*just barely*" assessment. However, if the question itself isn't about the science fiction aspects of the show, this site may not be the best fit; I seem to remember reading a meta question covering whether or not such questions are on-topic but I can't find it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist To clarify a bit: The question is of the "character background" sort. So, it is about the show and in-universe events. It just would happen to not likely be anything tied to the Sci-Fi aspect (in this case, "The Machine").

Comment: With how the last season ended, I think it's pretty much switched over to the "dystopian future" type of sci-fi...  We'll see how much it changes once it returns end of next month, I suppose

Answer (score 5):

I think that a question about the computer would be on-topic, but I think that questions about anything else should be asked on Movies and TV.

Comment: This.  The computer/program is 'above-now-tech'- as such, sci-fi.  Science-fiction isn't always two-thousand-years-away.  If this was a question about why dude-from-Lost didn't bleed out right away after a gunshot to the kidneys, elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I actually posted a [question on Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/is-person-of-interest-sci-fi) about this very issue, and I think the answer given is evidence that the show is on-topic here:

> From [an **interview**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/is-person-of-interest-sci-fi) *(July 2013)* with creator [**Jonathan Nolan**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0634300/):
>
> > ... A lot of people who don't watch the show think of it as a kind of crime procedural, but **we really think of it of it as a science fiction show.** We think of it as a genre show, there is a lot of comic book mythos woven into it...
>
> From [another **interview**](http://collider.com/person-of-interest-season-3-4-jonah-nolan-greg-plageman-interview/) *(October 2013, shorty after the start of Season 3):*
>
> > We know what next season —if we’re lucky enough to get a fourth season— we know what that’s about.
> >
> > I think viewers who have as much of **an affection for science fiction** —film, television— as we do, and a really good ear, will already know what next season is going to be, based on the first handful of episodes here.

If the creator believes he's making a Science Fiction show, who are we to say otherwise, regardless of what the question is?

Comment: That depends on the creator... I definitely wouldn't just be taking his word for it if it was a SyFy original.

Comment: @iszi - Especially when the sequel is titled "Person of Interest vs the Mega-Sharknado"